# Entity Framework thinks a column exists that does not

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I've got 2 tables:

```
InboxEvent
    int Id
    Visitor Owner
    [ForeignKey("Owner")]
    string OwnerId
    Visitor CausingUser
    [ForeignKey("CausingUser")]
    string CausingUserId

Visitor
    string Id
```

Both OwnerId and CausingUserId point to the Visitor table, yet in Sql Server Entity Framework has gone in and created the InboxEvent table like so:

```
FK OwnerId
FK CausingUserId
FK Visitor_Id
```

And, sure enough, it's invented a column:

```
NVarChar(128) Visitor_Id
```

OK... odd... Well simple enough, I'll kill the stray column with a Manual Migration:

```
public partial class KillInboxEventVisitor_Id : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.InboxEvent", "Visitor_Id", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropIndex("dbo.InboxEvent", "IX_Visitor_Id");
        DropColumn("dbo.InboxEvent", "Visitor_Id");
    }
```

Great, it's gone! And now... every time I try to get EF to save an InboxEvent:

```
db.InboxEvents.Add(new InboxEvent {...
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

EF explodes with

`SqlException: Invalid column name 'Visitor_Id'.`

How do I tell the underlying EF model this imagined column just does not exist?

## Edits / More Info

This is plain Entity Framework 6.x, with Asp.Net/OWIN Identity Framework, not the newer EF7/Core.

I was asked to show the full classes. Happy to, but, hold on to your butts, they were abbreviated above for a reason:

```
public class InboxEvent : IOwnerId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UserRead", 2)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The user whose Inbox this event is deposited into.
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("Owner"), Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    [Index("IX_UserRead", 0), Index]
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Visitor Owner { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_EventType_RelatedId1", 0)]
    public InboxEventType EventType { get; set; }

    public Posting.PostCore Post { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Post")]
    public int? PostId { get; set; }

    public Posting.PostReply Reply { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Reply")]
    public int? ReplyId { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UserRead", 1)]
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The user, if any, that caused/triggered this event. For example if A upvotes B, this is A, and B is Visitor.
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("CausingUser")]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string CausingUserId { get; set; }
    public Visitor CausingUser { get; set; }


    [Index]
    [Index("IX_EventType_RelatedId1", 1)]
    public int RelatedId1 { get; set; }

    public int RelatedId2 { get; set; }



    public InboxEvent()
    {
        CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}

public class Visitor : IdentityUser<string, LoginIdentity, StandardUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IVisitor
{
    [MaxLength(22), Column(TypeName = "Char"), Index]
    public string Uid { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(300), Index]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(300), Index]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime MemberOn { get; set; }
    

    public int Invites { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldReceiveReplyNotifications { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastEmailNotified { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100), Column(TypeName="VarChar")]
    public string ProfilePic { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserPhoto> UserPhotos { get; set; }
    public StaticImage StaticImage { get; set; }


    // BioViewModel
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(400)]    // TODO Normalize
    public string Disciplines { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string MissionStatement { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Tagline { get; set; }

    // SkillsViewModel
    [MaxLength(400)]
    public string SkillsKnown { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(400)]
    public string SkillsToLearn { get; set; }

    // PrefsViewModel
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string PhoneCountryCode { get; set; }
    //[MaxLength(20)]
    //public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }   // Already in base OWIN User model

    public ChatService ChatService { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string ChatHandle { get; set; }

    public byte PrefIpOpenness { get; set; }
    public byte PrefNonProfit { get; set; }
    public byte PrefMature { get; set; }

    public PrivacyLevel PrivacyNameCountryCity { get; set; }
    public PrivacyLevel PrivacyBio { get; set; }
    public PrivacyLevel PrivacySites { get; set; }
    public PrivacyLevel PrivacyCompanies { get; set; }
    public PrivacyLevel PrivacySkills { get; set; }
    public PrivacyLevel PrivacyContactInfo { get; set; }
    public PrivacyLevel PrivacyCollabPrefs { get; set; }

    public bool WantMonthlyNewsletter { get; set; }
    public bool WantToMentor { get; set; }
    public bool WantToVetProjects { get; set; }
    public bool WantToReviewProjects { get; set; }
    public bool WantToGiveFeedback { get; set; }

    // CommitmentViewModel
    public CommitmentChoice CommitmentChoice { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string CommitmentText { get; set; }


    public ICollection<CountryZip> CountryZips { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Org> Orgs { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserSite> UserSites { get; set; }


    public ICollection<DraftData> Drafts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Visitor_Team> Teams { get; set; }

    public ICollection<InboxEvent> Inbox { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SubscribedPost> PostSubscriptions { get; set; }



    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<Visitor, string> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }


    public Visitor()
    {
        CreatedOn = (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue;
        MemberOn = (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue;
        LastEmailNotified = (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue;
    }
}
```

Db does have an OnModelsCreating though it is unlikely to be relevant here:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Visitor>();
        // By default this is nvarchar max? Uh?
        entity.Property(v => v.PhoneNumber).HasMaxLength(20);
    }
```

Comment: It's better to show the real classes. There may be inaccuracies you're not aware of, but that may cause trouble.

Comment: EF doesn't create "stray" columns, so it makes sense that you will get errors if you just remove them. Like Gret says though, can you show us the actual POCO? Also if you have any code in the context that configures your context?

Comment: seems like one of the data annotations is either wrong or ignored by EF. EF won't create unnecessary columns, however it will create FK columns named like the shown, if it deems the current configuration unfit for the 1-to-many relationship at hand. I have more experience with Fluent API so I can't tell you what exactly to change, but fiddle around with these data annotations.

Comment: These things can be tricky to resolve. Start by telling us if this is about Core or Regular EF.

Comment: See [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) example which is similar and uses the `InverseProperty` annotation. Personally, I prefer fluent code to map each FK (also shown in link).

Comment: Also, is that the entire Visitor class? I've seen that problem when you try to define a single collection of InboxEvent in Visitor (you need 1 for each reference and InverseProperty or fluent code to link them).

Comment: Updated to answer above questions, including the very large full classes. EF6.

Comment: InverseProperty was it!! Had to add it on Inbox. @SteveGreene add your response as an Answer and you'll get the Checkbox.

Comment: Sorry @SteveGreene, I didn't see your comments and added an answer along those lines. Feel free to add your own answer and I'll remove mine.

Comment: Gave Gert an upvote, Steve when you post an Answer it'll get the Check. I'll check back tomorrow.

Comment: No biggie. I probably learned that from Gert on a past post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three associations between `Visitor` and `InboxEvent`. The two you showed initially:

```
public class InboxEvent : IOwnerId
{
    ...
    [ForeignKey("Owner"), Required]
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Visitor Owner { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CausingUser")]
    public string CausingUserId { get; set; }
    public Visitor CausingUser { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And:

```
public class Visitor : IdentityUser<string, ...
{
    ...
    public ICollection<InboxEvent> Inbox { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Without further notice, EF will assume that these associations are independent of each other: it will create three FKs, of which `Visitor_Id` is for the latter association.

You probably want `InboxEvent.Owner` and `Visitor.Inbox` to be two ends of one association, but EF doesn't know that and it's not going to guess. You have to make it explicit, for example by using the `[InverseProperty]` attribute:

```
public class InboxEvent : IOwnerId
{
    ...
    [ForeignKey("Owner"), Required]
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Inbox")]
    public Visitor Owner { get; set; }
    ...
}
```